# "touch" a DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a handy way to "touch" a DOM element? I'd like to remove the element and insert it again at the same position. Something like this:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element).appendChild(element);
```

except that appendChild inserts the element as the last sibling.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve by this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [insertBefore](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_insertbefore.asp) instead of appendChild.

```
var other = element.nextSibling;

if ( other ) {
  other.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  other.parentNode.insertBefore(element,other);
} else {
  other = element.parentNode;
  other.removeChild(element);
  other.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This creates a dummy text node to be used as a marker and replaces it with the node. Later when the node is to be re-inserted, replace it with the dummy node so the position is preserved.

[Node.replaceChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.replaceChild)

```
var dummy = document.createTextNode('');
var parent = element.parentNode;

parent.replaceChild(dummy, element); // replace with empty text node
parent.replaceChild(element, dummy); // swap out empty text node for original
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it would be better to use the DOM cloneNode(true) as it would retain all of the child nodes and properties:

```
// Copy the node.
var theOldChild = document.getElementById("theParent").childNodes[blah]
var theNewChild = theOldChild.cloneNode(true);

// Find the next Sibling
var nextSib = theOldChild.nextSibling();

// Remove the old Node
theOldChild.parentNode.removeChild(theOldChild)

// Append where it was.
nextSib.parentNode.inserertBefore(theNewChild, nextSib);
```

That is the way that I would do it as you can hold onto the variable "theNewChild" 100% as it was and insert it back into the document at any time.

Comment: why is this better? Saving a node in a variable before deleting will also save all children, no?

Comment: I do not believe it does. When you reference it in a variable you are referencing the element, not it's structure. Plus that is a reference to an existing object, It is not an HTML Fragment, the DOM should not allow you to reinsert that node elsewhere.